# How do I ssh from one Linux server to another using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, amazon-web-services, linux-kernel, aws-cli

I am trying to SSH from an EC2 tools Linux server to an on-prem Linux server. I am attempting to utilize the built-in OS module to SSH into another server, but my code is not currently accepting the password input...

The idea is that you run the python3 script and you type the name of the server you want ssh into and the script will pull the server credentials for AWS secrets manager and use the credential to open up an ssh session on another server.

#NOTE - I do not want to remotely run commands on another server, I simply want to run a python3 script to grab creds and ssh from one linux server to another..

```
import os

server_name = input("Enter server name: ")
input_value = f"aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id {server_name} --version-stage AWSCURRENT"


int_output = os.system(input_value)
string_output = os.popen(input_value).read()
json_output = json.loads(string_output)
secret_string = json_output['SecretString']
json_secrets = json.loads(secret_string)
server_ip = json_secrets['server_ip']
server_user = json_secrets['server_user']
server_pw = json_secrets['server_password']
os.system(f"ssh {server_user}@{server_name}")
os.system(f"{sever_pw}")
os.system(f"\n")
```

The issue that I have is when I execute the python3 script on the EC2 instance, I am being prompted to enter a password... This is an issue because the password should have been applied with the server_pw variable that the script executed. I stored the password input as a variable and printed and verified that it has the correct password.

Does anyone have an idea as to why the password command to verify credentials for SSH is failing in this instance?

Comment: Have you considered storing SSH keys in parameter store instead of passwords? Or using SSM?

Comment: What @jordanm said; use a keypair. Failing that, look at [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) ... your password is being sent into the void (it's not sent being sent to the same shell as the ssh command).

Comment: Usually ppl use [Fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/) or something similar for that.

Comment: @jordanm the parameter store option is not a possibility in my environment. I am unfortunately restricted to passwords at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate response to

```
os.system(f"ssh {server_user}@{server_name}")
```

is to prompt for a password. The script isn't getting to the next line before it prompts. If you quit out of the password prompt then your password would be written straight after.

You might have to use an alternative SSH client, such as `sshpass` that accepts multiple command-line arguments, including password.

You could also try piping the password e.g.

```
echo $PASSWORD | os.system(f"ssh {server_user}@{server_name}")
```